# Permutation and Combinations on Calculator

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations, calculator

How can I calculate permutation and combinations on a calculator using nPr and nCr? I want to compute with nPr and nCr buttons.

Comment: Do your calculator have factorial operator?

Comment: Are you asking how to use the nPr, nCr buttons/operations? Or how to compute them without those buttons?

Comment: @Max I want to compute with nPr and nCr buttons

Comment: What calculator do you have - manufacturer and model?

Comment: @Moo fx-82AU PLUS. This is a Casio brand.

Comment: Page 16: item 13 of http://casio.edu.monacocorp.co.nz/products/fx82ausplus/pdf/fx82AU_PLUS%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what calculator. You can use the formulas $$ nCr = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$$ and $$ nPr = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$
if you have access to a factorial.

Comment: Also, some calculators have buttons with $P$ and $C$ (my one has these above the $\times$ and $\div$ operators), which may make it quicker.